# Custom Post Type Permalinks with %category%

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, permalinks

I Create New Post Types and Taxonomies. This is the script:

```
add_action('init', 'my_custom_post_type_init');
function my_custom_post_type_init()
{
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x('Roundabouts', 'post type general name'),
    'singular_name' => _x('Roundabout', 'post type singular name'),
    'add_new' => _x('Add New', 'Roundabout'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Add New Roundabout'),
    'edit_item' => __('Edit Roundabout'),
    'new_item' => __('New Roundabout'),
    'view_item' => __('View Roundabout'),
    'search_items' => __('Search Roundabouts'),
    'not_found' =>  __('No Roundabouts found'),
    'not_found_in_trash' => __('No Roundabouts found in Trash'),
    'parent_item_colon' => ''
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_queryable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'menu_position' => 5,
    'rewrite' => array('slug' => '%category%', 'with_front' => FALSE),
    'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag', 'category'),
    'supports' => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments', 'thumbnail')
  );
  register_post_type('roundabouts',$args);
}
```

and this is the permalink setting which I am not allowed to change.

```
/%category%/%postname%/
```

Now I required to generate permalink like:

```
http://my_site/category_name/post_title
```

while google I found many articles, issues:

- [Permalinks 404 with custom post type](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/permalinks-404-with-custom-post-type)
- [Custom Permalinks for Custom Post Types in WordPress 3.0+](http://xplus3.net/2010/05/20/wp3-custom-post-type-permalinks/)
- [custom post type with post_id in permalink structure](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/custom-post-type-permalink-structure)

but almost waste 4 hours of my life then after complete R&D at last I found

- [Custom Post Type Permalinks](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks-part-2)

which somehow convert my post permalink to as I require but if I hit that link I get the 404 error.

Here is the modified script which is best suitable with my above code:

```
// Add filter to plugin init function
add_filter('post_type_link', 'gallery_permalink', 10, 3);  
// Adapted from get_permalink function in wp-includes/link-template.php
function gallery_permalink($permalink, $post_id, $leavename) {
    $post = get_post($post_id);

    $rewritecode = array(
        '%year%',
        '%monthnum%',
        '%day%',
        '%hour%',
        '%minute%',
        '%second%',
        $leavename? '' : '%postname%',
        '%post_id%',
        '%category%',
        '%author%',
        $leavename? '' : '%pagename%',
    );

    if ( '' != $permalink && !in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft')) ) {

        $unixtime = strtotime($post->post_date);

        $category = '';
        if ( strpos($permalink, '%category%') !== false ) {

            $cats = get_the_category($post->ID);
            if ( $cats ) {
                usort($cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID'); // order by ID
                $category = $cats[0]->slug;
                if ( $parent = $cats[0]->parent )
                    $category = get_category_parents($parent, false, '/', true) . $category;
            }
            // show default category in permalinks, without
            // having to assign it explicitly
            if ( empty($category) ) {
                $default_category = get_category( get_option( 'default_category' ) );
                $category = is_wp_error( $default_category ) ? '' : $default_category->slug;
            }
        }

        $author = '';
        if ( strpos($permalink, '%author%') !== false ) {
            $authordata = get_userdata($post->post_author);
            $author = $authordata->user_nicename;
        }

        $date = explode(" ",date('Y m d H i s', $unixtime));
        $rewritereplace =
        array(
            $date[0],
            $date[1],
            $date[2],
            $date[3],
            $date[4],
            $date[5],
            $post->post_name,
            $post->ID,
            $category,
            $author,
            $post->post_name,
        );
        $permalink = str_replace($rewritecode, $rewritereplace, $permalink);
    } else { // if they're not using the fancy permalink option
    }
    return $permalink;
}
```

Please guide me what additional I could do.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment on your scripts, but if you change anything related to permalinks - it is always advisable to go to the Dashboard -> Settings -> Permalinks and click the "Update" button. This tells Wordpress to flush its rewrite rules. If your script is correct, then after doing the "Update" - you won't get 404 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to sanchothefat for this plugin it really solve my problem.

[WP Permastructure](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-permastructure/)

Comment: Please mark your answer as correct using the green tick